# jquery selector, closest, siblings combination

Tags: php, jquery

I have the following html:-

```
<ul class="nav-list">
    <li><a style="cursor:pointer;"><span class="hello"> ></span>OVERVIEW</a> 
        <ul here>
            <li id="Overview"><a href="/en/overview">OVERVIEW</a>


        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I wish to, when click span class hello, the ul here will add a class, and I attempted the following:-

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('.hello').click(function(){
        $(this).siblings().find('ul').addClass('hello');
    })  
})
</script>
```

How shall I handle the sublings, parent and children and find ('ul') in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('.hello').click(function(){
        $(this).closest("li").find('ul').addClass('hello');
    })  
})
</script>
```

reference [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) , [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

Answer (score 1):

The `ul` is the next sibling of the parent `li` element

```
$(function(){
    $('.hello').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().next().addClass('hello');
    })  
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xLrak/)

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('.hello').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().siblings().find('ul').addClass('hello');
    })  
})
</script>
```

the span doent hav eany sibling ul,its parent has

Comment: Actually the parent of the `<span>` is an `<a>`, but your code still works as the `<ul>` is the sibling of this `<a>

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in two ways:

### 1: traverse up with .closest() and use .find()

```
$('.hello').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('li').find('ul').addClass('hello');
})
```

### 2: Get the elem at 1 level up with .parent() and use .siblings()

```
$('.hello').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().siblings('ul').addClass('hello');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('.hello').click(function(){
        $(this).closest("li").find('ul').addClass('hello');
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

According to http://api.jquery.com/find/

you do not need the `siblings()` call

```
$(this).find('ul').addClass('hello');
```

will be fine

Answer (score 0):

One easy way can be, inside the click listener:

```
$(this).closest("li").find("ul").addClass("hello");
```

With closest you have the li container, then you can find the right sibiling ul in the container.

I use this solution instead of the .parent() because it not rely on the position of the element in the DOM and it still work if you wrap the span or the anchor in another tag, for any reason.